# Can't find my Automator service action in the Keyboard Shortcuts list

Tags: macos, finder, automator, services

I've made a very simple Automator service (moves some selected files into a new folder). It works fine via the Services -> menu.

So now I'd like to add a keyboard shortcut to launch this action from Finder, but I'm unable to. According to every person on the internet, I can go into System Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts, select 'Services' on left panel, then scroll to bottom of right hand list and my service will be listed in the 'General' section. But it's not listed; I only see three items relating to unarchiving.

I've searched the web for people with this same issue but can't find any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it receives files or folders as input, it should be in the files and folders section and not the general section.

Was the service saved to ~/Library/Services/?

Comment: Argh! It is indeed in Files and Folders, I thought I checked the whole list earlier on -- maybe I did that before re-launching the Keyboard prefs pane. Thanks!